# Change of variables for Stefan problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am trying to reproduce that the Stefan problem is nonlinear by normalizing the domain. In Section 1.2 of [1] (p. 24), they claim that the heat diffusion equation $T_t = \alpha_L T_{xx}$ in the time varying domain $0<x<X(t)$ (Stefan problem) can be normalized by change of variables leading to a nonlinear equation (I guess $X'= X_t$.):

> The underlying geometric nonlinearity can be made to appear algebraically in the partial differential equations by a
> change of variables: replacing $x$ by $\xi = x/X(t)$ transforms the varying region $0 < x < X(t)$ to the fixed region $0 < \xi < 1$, and the linear equation $T_t = \alpha_L T_{xx}$ to the nonlinear equation $X^2 T_t - \xi XX'T_\xi = \alpha_L T_{\xi\xi}$ (see §**3.3**).

However I somehow cannot figure out what the steps are in between. Could someone explain to me what the steps and rules are if $x = \xi X$ in $T_{xx} = T_{\xi X \xi X}$?

[1] V. Alexiades, A. D. Solomon, *Mathematical modeling of melting and freezing processes*, Routledge, 1993. [doi:10.1201/9780203749449](https://doi.org/10.1201/9780203749449)

Comment: $X'$ is almost certainly the time derivative of $X$, which would make sense in terms of units as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us introduce the change of variables $T(x,t) = \theta(\xi, t)$ where $\xi = x/X(t)$. According to the chain and product rules, partial differentiation with respect to $x$ gives
\begin{aligned}
T_x &= \theta_\xi \xi_x,\\
T_{xx} &= \theta_{\xi\xi} (\xi_x)^2 + \theta_\xi \xi_{xx},
\end{aligned}
where $\xi_x = 1/X$ and $\xi_{xx} = 0$.
Computation of the total derivative in time gives
$$
\tfrac{\text d}{\text d t} T = T_t = \theta_\xi \xi_t + \theta_t
$$
where $\xi_t = -xX'/X^2 = -\xi X'/X$. It follows that the Stefan problem $T_t = \alpha_L T_{xx}$ with the moving domain $0<x<X(t)$ becomes
$$
\theta_t - \xi X'X^{-1} \theta_\xi = \alpha_L \theta_{\xi\xi} X^{-2}, \qquad 0<\xi<1,
$$
which ends the proof (upto renaming $\theta$ as $T$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It is really clear. Maybe I have never learned properly how to introduce the change of variables. I didn't start it the way you did so I just struggled around.